# Spirit Qi: Error when replacing sequence with expectation operator

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a grammar that works perfectly fine and contains the following lines.

```
element = container | list | pair;
container = name >> '(' >> -(arg % ',') >> ')' >> '{' >> +element > '}';
// trying to put an expectation operator here --------^
list = name >> '(' > (value % ',') > ')' > ';';
pair = name >> ':' > value > ';';
```

To have meaningful error messages, I want to make sure that `container` does not backtrack as soon as it hits `'{'`. But for some reason, if I replace the sequence operator with an expectation operator right after the `'{'`, I get a huge compiler error. Any ideas what the problem might be?

`element` is a `boost::variant`; `container`, `list` and `pair` are own structs with `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` applied. Please have a look here for the full source code: https://github.com/fklemme/liberty_tool/blob/master/src/liberty_grammar.hpp#L24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because the precedences of `operator>>` and `operator>` aren't equal, the resulting synthesized attribute type is different.

In fact, it is no longer automatically compatible with the intended exposed attribute type.

In this case the problem can be quickly neutralized with some disambiguating parentheses around the sub-expression:

```
container = name >> '(' >> -(arg % ',') >> ')' >> ('{' > +element > '}');
```